# No ruby-devel in RHEL7?

Tags: ruby, redhat

I have a recently installed RHEL7 system, and need to do gem install jekyll, however this fails as:

```
Fetching: yajl-ruby-1.2.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h
```

Google suggest this is due to the lack of a ruby-devel package being installed. However there doesn't seem to *be* such a package in RHEL7. Do I need to move to a software collection (don't really want to do this as this will be for a production machine, not development) or can I get it some other way?

Comment: Did you try RPM ruby devel? http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ruby-devel

Comment: rpmfind isn't listing any version for redhat 7 - this is the problem. I'm not going to install a random apckage from a different distro/version as that's just asking for problems. We'd also quite like to find a package repository-based solution so we get useful things like security updates...

Answer (score 32):

This answer comes by way of piecing together bits from other answers - so to the previous contributors...thank you because I would not have figured this out.

This example is based on the RHEL 7 AMI (Amazon Managed Image) 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64.

So by default as mentioned above the `optional` repository is not enabled. Don't add another repo.d file as it already exists just that it is disabled.

1. To enable first you need the name. I used grep to do this:

   ```
   grep -B1 -i optional /etc/yum.repos.d/*
   ```

   above each name will be the repo id enclosed in `[ ]` look for the optional **not** `optional-source`
2. Enable the optional repo:

   ```
   yum-config-manager --enable <repo-id>
   ```
3. Refresh the yum cache (not sure if this is necessary but it doesn't hurt):

   ```
   sudo yum makecache
   ```
4. Finally, you can install `ruby-devel`:

   ```
   yum install ruby-devel
   ```

Depending on your user's permissions you may need to use `sudo`.

Comment: this works should be marked as answer. Thanks juice!

Comment: Thanks a million. This enabled me to do `gem install compass`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to subscribe to the *optional* repo to get all the devel packages.

```
subscription-manager repos  --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```

This is because the `ruby-devel` package is contained in the `rhel-7-server-optional-rpms` repository.

Answer (score 2):

At least on Oracle Linux 7 you have to enable an additional repo.

```
[root@foo ~]# yum repolist
repo id                     repo name 
[...]
ol7_optional_latest/x86_64  Oracle Linux 7Server Optional Latest (x86_64)
```

After enabling the repo `ruby-devel` sits there, awaiting your installation.

```
[root@foo ~]# yum info ruby-devel | egrep 'Name|Version|From'
Name        : ruby-devel
Version     : 2.0.0.598
From repo   : ol7_optional_latest
```

That's all.

Comment: there is only i686  (version) in RHEL 7 ? Name       : ruby-devel
Architektur : i686
Version    : 1.8.6.111
Ausgabe    : 1

Answer (score 2):

ruby-devel RPM is available in the following repo on RHEL 7

rhel-7-server-optional-beta-rpms

Set "enabled = 1" for this repo in your .repo file and then run

`yum install ruby-devel`

Answer (score 0):

additional repos are available to your RHEL 7

```
# yum -y install yum-utils
# yum repolist all
```

This will list all available repos. Enable the repo you need. The devel packages are in extras for instance:

```
# yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras
```

After performing these steps, I could then install ruby-devel, augeas-devel and install/compile

```
# gem install ruby-augeas
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up downloading the package from:

https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ruby-devel

In RHEL7.5, this package can be installed with:

```
rpm -ivh ruby-devel-2.0.0.648-33.el7_4.x86_64.rpm
```

Also, the development tools can be installed before that using:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Answer (score -1):

Install ruby package on your system and try again.

```
sudo yum install ruby193-ruby-devel.x86_64
```

Comment: ruby is already installed. There are no ruby193-* packages available on the system. You need the developer software collection for that package I think?

Comment: This did not solve the issue package still not found on RHEL 7 AMI

Answer (score -1):

You can download from:

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/ruby-devel(x86-64)

Something like this would work:

```
wget ftp://bo.mirror.garr.it/1/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/Packages/ruby-devel-2.0.0.598-25.el7_1.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh ruby-devel-2.0.0.598-25.el7_1.x86_64.rpm
```